# React Styled Components use value of property for check

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

```
const LinkWrapper = styled.div`
  font-weight: ${props => (props.unread={"UNREAD"}) ? "regular" : "bold"}
`

<LinkWrapper className="g-email-list" href={`${e.id}`} key={e.id} unread={e.messages[0].labelIds[0]}>
```

Based on the value of the LinkWrapper prop "unread" the styled component should either pick regular or bold.

How do I feed the value of the prop into the styled component as an argument?

Comment: Almost there, `props.unread === "UNREAD"` in your ternary statement

Comment: Cheers! That worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
const LinkWrapper = styled.div`
  font-weight: ${props => props.unread === "UNREAD" ? "bold" : "regular" }
`
```

### API:
https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced

Comment: I've read about that, but your code doesn't actually check for the outcome of the prop.

Maybe my question wasn't clear enough.

If props.unread === UNREAD, it should style bold.
If props.unread === INBOX, it should style regular.

Comment: Yes that worked for me. ljbc1994 just beat you to the answer, cheers for being helpful.